# MySQL Count rows of multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, count

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW organizedevent AS

    SELECT o.organizerID AS "Organizer ID", 
           o.organizerName AS "Name",
           o.contact AS "Contact",  
           COUNT(e.eventID) AS "Organized Event"
    FROM   Organizer o ,Event e
    WHERE  o.organizerID=e.organizerID
    GROUP BY o.organizerID,o.organizerName,o.contact,eventID
    HAVING COUNT(e.eventID) >=1
    ORDER BY o.organizerID ASC;
```

I need how to write the join table statement to get the answer as I want the answer like `ORG1058` have count 2 and `ORG1059` have count 6.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to remove `eventID` of GROUP BY clause?

Comment: If you are using MySQL as the title of your question suggests, tag your question with `mysql` instead of `sql-server` (Microsoft SQL Server).